# Where is indentation problem in my Python code?

Tags: python, compiler-errors, syntax-error, indentation, pylance

I'm trying to solve my homework coding assignment, but I'm facing a indentation error in my code. I spent quite long time now tryibg to figure out what I'm doing wrong but I don't see the error. Moreover, a friend of mine has a very similar code and it works just fine for him.

The Indentation error being raised after I add lines 141 and 142.
Starts in main() function with word "with". Click to see the image ->
[Indent error lines 141, 142](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NUVKu.png)

I also tried to put the functionality in separate function, and when I try to call it in main(), I face the same error. Full code attached below.

Thank you community!

`

```py
#Imports
import sys
import os
from bitstring import BitArray

#Declaration of variables
op = ''
rt = ''
rs = ''
imm = ''
ans = ''
shamt = ''
funct = ''
comm = ''
RegDst = ''
ALUSrc = ''
MemtoReg = ''
RegWrite = ''
MemRead = ''
MemWrite = ''
branch = ''
ALUOp1 = ''
ALUOp2 = ''
zeroBit = ''
oper = ''

#Dictionaries
opDict = {'001000' : 'addi', '000000' : {'100000' : 'add', '100010' : 'sub'}}
regValues = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
regMap = {'00000' : 0 , '00001' : 1, '00010' : 2, '00011' : 3, '00100' : 4, '00101' : 5, '00110' : 6, '00111' : 7}


#Main function

        
def program(request, newFile, newFileTwo, count):
    splitInput(request, newFile)
    ans = str(regValues).replace(",", "")
    ans = ans.replace("[","")
    ans = ans.replace("]","")
    ans = ans.replace(" ","|")  
    newFileTwo.write(str(count) + "|" + ans + '\n')

#Utility functions
def splitInput(inn, file):
    op = inn[0:6]
    if (op == '001000'):
        # I-Type
        rt = inn[6:11]
        rs = inn[11:16]
        imm = inn[16:32]
        b = BitArray(bin=imm)
        ans = b.int
        oper = 'addi'
        decideCtrl(oper, file)
        addi(rt, rs, ans)
    elif (op == '000000'):
        # R - Type
        rs = inn[6:11]
        rt = inn[11:16]
        rd = inn[16:21]
        shamt = inn[21:26]
        funct = inn[26:33].replace("\n", "")
        # Add / Sub
        if(opDict['000000'][funct] == 'add'):
            # Add command
            oper = 'add'
            decideCtrl(oper, file)
            add(rs,rt,rd)
        elif(opDict['000000'][funct] == 'sub'):
            # Sub Command
            oper = 'sub'
            decideCtrl(oper, file)
            sub(rd, rs, rt)

 
#Dedice on control signals
def decideCtrl(op, file):
    match op:
        case 'add':
            RegDst = '1'
            RegWrite = '1'
            ALUSrc = '0'
            MemtoReg = '0'
            RegWrite = '1'
            MemRead = '0'
            MemWrite = '0'
            branch = '0'
            ALUOp1 = '1'
            ALUOp2 = '0'
            comm = 'add'
            file.write(RegDst + ALUSrc + MemtoReg + RegWrite + MemRead + MemWrite + branch + ALUOp1 + ALUOp2 +'\n')
        case 'sub':
            RegDst = '1'
            RegWrite = '1'
            ALUSrc = '0'
            MemtoReg = '0'
            RegWrite = '1'
            MemRead = '0'
            MemWrite = '0'
            branch = '0'
            ALUOp1 = '1'
            ALUOp2 = '0'
            comm = 'sub'
            file.write(RegDst + ALUSrc + MemtoReg + RegWrite + MemRead + MemWrite + branch + ALUOp1 + ALUOp2 + '\n')
        case 'addi':
            RegDst = '0'
            RegWrite = '1'
            ALUSrc = '1'
            MemtoReg = '0'
            RegWrite = '1'
            MemRead = '0'
            MemWrite = '0'
            branch = '0'
            ALUOp1 = '0'
            ALUOp2 = '0'
            comm = 'addi'
            file.write(RegDst + ALUSrc + MemtoReg + RegWrite + MemRead + MemWrite + branch + ALUOp1 + ALUOp2 + '\n')

#Commands
def add(rs, rt, rd):
    regValues[regMap[rd]] = regValues[regMap[rs]] + regValues[regMap[rt]]

def sub(rd, rs, rt):
    regValues[regMap[rd]] = regValues[regMap[rs]] - regValues[regMap[rt]]

def addi(rt, rs, imm):
    regValues[regMap[rs]] = regValues[regMap[rt]] + imm
    
   

def main():
    PCount = 65536
    count = 0
    # inputName = str(sys.argv[1])
    # F = open(inputName, "r")

    with open(filename, "r") as file:
        storedLines = file.read().splitlines()

    newFile = open("outputOne.txt", "w")
    newFileTwo = open("outputTwo.txt", "w")

    
    
    ans = str(regValues).replace(",", "")
    ans = ans.replace("[","")
    ans = ans.replace("]","")
    ans = ans.replace(" ","|")  
    newFileTwo.write(str(PCount) + "|" + ans + '\n')
    
    # for comms in F:
    #   if (count == 100):
    #       F.close()
    #       newFile.close()
    #       newFileTwo.close()
    #       exit()
    #   PCount = PCount + 4
    #   program(comms, newFile, newFileTwo, PCount)
    #   count = count + 1


    
    #F.close()
    newFile.close()
    newFileTwo.close()  


# Use open file to store the lines with their indicies
# When beq or bne compare and if it's true -> grab the label imm -> convert to decimal
# -> divide by 4 to get actual line

# Ad

# While i less than size of array of lines go one by one and do logic
#   storedLines[i] - line of a code in a file. Do logic to each [i]
# Add internal pc counter (intpc=0). By each iteration of i intpc goes +4
# at the end  of while loop internalPC = 4
# i == internalPC // 4

# App Entry Point
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

`

- Compared my code to friend's and it looks like it works for him (The same lines, 141, 142)
- Tried to put functionality in separate function -> Does not work
- I expect the code to put the all contents of a provided file into array using with

Comment: Likely to be a tab-vs-space thing.  Make sure you're using the same type of indentation all the way through your function.  (You can configure your IDE to automatically normalize them when you save, which completely avoids this type of problem.)

Answer (score 0):

I've fixed the indentation errors I was able to find in your code, made some changes to it, and added some remark comments as `"# NOTE: ..."`:

```py
# == Necessary Imports =========================================================
import sys
import os

from bitstring import BitArray


# == Variables =================================================================
op = ""
rt = ""
rs = ""
imm = ""
ans = ""
shamt = ""
funct = ""
comm = ""
RegDst = ""
ALUSrc = ""
MemtoReg = ""
RegWrite = ""
MemRead = ""
MemWrite = ""
branch = ""
ALUOp1 = ""
ALUOp2 = ""
zeroBit = ""
oper = ""

# == Dictionaries ==============================================================
opDict = {"001000": "addi", "000000": {"100000": "add", "100010": "sub"}}
regValues = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
regMap = {
    "00000": 0,
    "00001": 1,
    "00010": 2,
    "00011": 3,
    "00100": 4,
    "00101": 5,
    "00110": 6,
    "00111": 7,
}


# == Main Function =============================================================
def program(request, newFile, newFileTwo, count):
    splitInput(request, newFile)
    ans = (
        str(count)
        + "|"
        + str(regValues)
        .replace(",", "")
        .replace("[", "")
        .replace("]", "")
        .replace(" ", "|")
        + "\n"
    )
    newFileTwo.write(ans)


# == Utility Function ==========================================================
def splitInput(inn, file):
    op = inn[:6]
    if op == "000000":
        # R-Type
        rs = inn[6:11]
        rt = inn[11:16]
        rd = inn[16:21]
        # NOTE: `shamt` shadows the global variable `shamt`.
        shamt = inn[21:26]
        # NOTE: `funct` shadows the global variable `funct`.
        funct = inn[26:33].replace("\n", "")

        # Add / Sub
        if opDict["000000"][funct] == "add":
            decideCtrl("add", file)
            add(rs, rt, rd)
        elif opDict["000000"][funct] == "sub":
            decideCtrl("sub", file)
            sub(rd, rs, rt)

    elif op == "001000":
        # I-Type
        # NOTE: `rt` shadows the global variable `rt`.
        rt = inn[6:11]
        # NOTE: `rs` shadows the global variable `rs`.
        rs = inn[11:16]
        # NOTE: `imm` shadows the global variable `imm`.
        imm = inn[16:32]
        # NOTE: `ans` shadows the global variable `ans`.
        ans = BitArray(bin=imm).int
        decideCtrl("addi", file)
        addi(rt, rs, ans)


# Dedice on control signals
def decideCtrl(op, file):
    RegDst = "1"
    ALUSrc = "0"
    MemtoReg = "0"
    RegWrite = "1"
    MemRead = "0"
    MemWrite = "0"
    branch = "0"
    ALUOp1 = "1"
    ALUOp2 = "0"

    match op:
        case "add":
            # NOTE: `comm` seems to be unused.
            # NOTE: `comm` shadows the global variable `comm`.
            comm = "add"

        case "sub":
            # NOTE: `comm` seems to be unused.
            # NOTE: `comm` shadows the global variable `comm`.
            comm = "sub"

        case "addi":
            RegDst = "0"
            ALUSrc = "1"
            ALUOp1 = "0"
            # NOTE: `comm` seems to be unused.
            # NOTE: `comm` shadows the global variable `comm`.
            comm = "addi"

    file.write(RegDst + ALUSrc + MemtoReg + RegWrite + MemRead + MemWrite
               + branch + ALUOp1 + ALUOp2 + "\n")


# == Functions =================================================================
# NOTE: renamed the function parameters to avoid shadowing the global variables.x
def add(_rs, _rt, _rd):
    regValues[regMap[_rd]] = regValues[regMap[_rs]] + regValues[regMap[_rt]]


# NOTE: renamed the function parameters to avoid shadowing the global variables.x
def sub(_rd, _rs, _rt):
    regValues[regMap[_rd]] = regValues[regMap[_rs]] - regValues[regMap[_rt]]


# NOTE: renamed the function parameters to avoid shadowing the global variables.x
def addi(_rt, _rs, _imm):
    regValues[regMap[_rs]] = regValues[regMap[_rt]] + _imm


def main():

    PCount = 65536
    # NOTE: commented this line, because it's not being used anywhere.
    # QUESTION: where do you define the variable "filename"?
    # with open(filename, mode="r", encoding="utf-8") as file:
    #     storedLines = file.read().splitlines()

    ans = (
        str(regValues)
        .replace(",", "")
        .replace("[", "")
        .replace("]", "")
        .replace(" ", "|")
    )
    # NOTE: specified the `encoding` parameter, as it's a good practice.
    # NOTE: modified to `with open` as it's a good practice.
    with open("outputTwo.txt", mode = "w", encoding = "utf-8") as newFileTwo,\
        open("outputOne.txt", mode = "w", encoding = "utf-8") as newFile:
        newFileTwo.write(f"{PCount}|{ans}\n")

        # NOTE: creating some sample data for `F`, as I couldn't find it anywhere.
        F = [
            "0010000000000000000000000000000000",
            "0010000000000000000000000000000000",
            "0010000000000000000000000000000000",
            "0010000000000000000000000000000000",
            "0010000000000000000000000000000000",
            "0010000000000000000000000000000000",
            "0010000000000000000000000000000000",
            "0010000000000000000000000000000000",
            "0010000000000000000000000000000000",
            "0010000000000000000000000000000000",
        ]

        for count, comms in enumerate(F):
            if count == 100:
                # newFile.close()     # If you use `with open`, you dont't need to close the file.
                # newFileTwo.close()  # If you use `with open`, you dont't need to close the file.
                exit()
            PCount += 4
            program(comms, newFile, newFileTwo, PCount)


# Use open file to store the lines with their indicies
# When beq or bne compare and if:
# true -> grab label imm -> convert to decimal -> divide by 4 to get actual line

# Ad
# While `i` is less than the size of the lines array, iterate through it,
# and do the following logic:
#   storedLines[i] - line of a code in a file. Do logic to each [i]
# Add internal pc counter (`intpc=0`). By each iteration of `i`, `intpc` goes +4
# at the end  of while loop internalPC = 4
# i == internalPC // 4

# App Entry Point
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```